# Type mismatch in struct values

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct book
    {
        char name[20];
        float price;
    };
    struct book b={5};
    printf("%f\n",b.price);
    return 0;
}
```

So what is happening to the 5 that is being passed? Where is it getting stored? Or is it not getting stored at all?

Even if I print b.name, nothing is being printed.

Comment: 5 isn't a printable character. Try something larger like 65. they try and print name.

Answer (score 5):

The `5` is being used as initializer for the first element of the struct. That happens to be an array, so the `5` initializes the first element of that array.

In C, if you use a brace-enclosed initializer then all elements get initialized; and ones you don't specify get 0. So it is the same as:

```
struct book b = { 
    {5, 0, 0, 0, /* ... */ },
    0
};
```

Your `printf` on the float will print `0`.  If you try to print `b.name` as a string then you will print the string containing one character whose value is `5`. On most systems this will be a non-printable character so you may get no visible output.

To get the `5` back you could do: `printf("%d\n", b.name[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

Initialisation happens in structure in the order of your values being passed at the time of creating variable of type `struct` just after declaring it.so `5` naturally flows to the first element of the character array.so 5 is stored as fist element of the character array.while initialising the `struct` type variable you cannot skip the variables for initialisation,you have to follow the order of declaration of the variables inside the `structure` for there initialisation.Matt McNabb answer says the